# How get the pointer on custom AlertDialog from onClick method?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I create my custom `AlertDialog` from layout with layoutInflater. In this layout i found my Buttons and set the `OnClickListener` on this Buttons. The problem is, in method `onClick` not present `DialogInterface` and i cant do `dialog.dissmiss`. How can I get the pointer on my AlertDialog, or maybe on `DialogInterface`?

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myApp.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null);
    ((Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.downloadButton)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //in this, i want to dissmiss dialog
            //some code
        }
    });
```

I dont want the to save the pointer on Dialog on Class attribute - maybe other way are exist?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do in the following way by using Dialog class.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MAinActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login_popup);
Button dialogButtonOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);

dialogButtonOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                       dialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats what I need! I can`t use AlertDialog because it creates AFTER creating Buailder. Dialog solved this problem. Thanks, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I was just working on this...  I hope I didn't delete anything important out of it that wasn't irrelevant to what you are doing.

```
public class updateDialog extends AlertDialog implements AlertDialog.OnClickListener {
    updateDialog(Context context, Object sent)
    {
        super(context,R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
        // Inflate your view
        View myView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.update_sql,null);
        // Set it to be the view
        setView(myView);
        // Set up buttons
        setButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE, context.getString(Cancel), this);
        setButton(BUTTON_NEUTRAL,context.getString(R.string.Propose), this);
        setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, context.getString(R.string.Restore),  this);
    }

    // Handle buttons
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        switch (i)
        {
            case BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                // Dismiss the dialog.
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                break;
            case BUTTON_NEUTRAL:
                break;
            case BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Mostly the key is NOT to use the builder, but to build it yourself.